# How can I scan a maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, parsing, maven-indexer

I'm developing a code-sharing plugin for eclipse (for a bachelor thesis project).

Currently I'm trying to scan a maven repository and generate a package list.

I can download and parse a pom.xml using the maven.model classes, but I can't figure out which maven classes are responsible for parsing of archetype-catalog.xml

Is there a non maven parser?

Can I just scan the entire repository tree for pom.xml files?

edit:
Ive found   nexus-indexer but i have no idea hot to  use it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took ages but i finally found a working example

```java
PlexusContainer plexus =  new DefaultPlexusContainer();

NexusIndexer n = (NexusIndexer) plexus.lookup(NexusIndexer.class);
IndexUpdater iu = (IndexUpdater) plexus.lookup(IndexUpdater.class);

// DefaultNexusIndexer n = new DefaultNexusIndexer();
List<IndexCreator> indexCreators = new ArrayList<IndexCreator>();
// IndexingContext c = n.addIndexingContext("test", "test",new File( "/home/tomas/Desktop/test"),new File( "/home/tomas/Desktop/index"), "http://repository.jboss.org/", null);
Directory tempIndexDirectory = new RAMDirectory();

// IndexCreator min = new MinimalArtifactInfoIndexCreator();
// MavenPluginArtifactInfoIndexCreator mavenPlugin = new MavenPluginArtifactInfoIndexCreator();
// MavenArchetypeArtifactInfoIndexCreator mavenArchetype = new MavenArchetypeArtifactInfoIndexCreator();
// JarFileContentsIndexCreator jar = new JarFileContentsIndexCreator();
// IndexCreator min = plexus.lookup(IndexCreator.class, MinimalArtifactInfoIndexCreator.ID);
IndexCreator mavenPlugin = plexus.lookup( IndexCreator.class, MavenPluginArtifactInfoIndexCreator.ID );
IndexCreator mavenArchetype = plexus.lookup( IndexCreator.class, MavenArchetypeArtifactInfoIndexCreator.ID );
IndexCreator jar = plexus.lookup( IndexCreator.class, JarFileContentsIndexCreator.ID );
indexCreators.add(min);
indexCreators.add(mavenPlugin);
indexCreators.add(mavenArchetype);
indexCreators.add(jar);

IndexingContext c = n.addIndexingContext(
    "temp", "test", new File("/home/tomas/Desktop/mavenTest"), 
    tempIndexDirectory, "http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/",
    null, indexCreators
);

IndexUpdateRequest ur=new IndexUpdateRequest(c);
ur.setForceFullUpdate(true);
iu.fetchAndUpdateIndex(ur);

// for (String s : c.getAllGroups()) {
//     System.out.println(s);
// }

BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();
q.add(n.constructQuery(ArtifactInfo.GROUP_ID, "*"), Occur.SHOULD);

FlatSearchRequest request = new FlatSearchRequest(q);
FlatSearchResponse response = n.searchFlat(request);

for (ArtifactInfo a : response.getResults()) {
    String bUrl=url+a`enter code here`.groupId+"/"+a.artifactId+"/"+a.version+"/";
    String fileName=a.artifactId+"-"+a.version;
    System.out.println(bUrl+fileName+"."+a.packaging);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the `nexus-indexer` has been [donated to the Apache Foundation](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/02/maven-indexer-sonatypes-donation-to-repository-search/) and is now known as the `maven-indexer`. There is a [github mirror](https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer) and the project is also listed at the [Apache Git page](http://git.apache.org)

Answer (score 0):

Scanning my local repository for packages would be pretty slick.  I would have a ton of duplicated packages that would need to be considered before I shared anything.  Since yesterday I was building version 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT to my repository and today I'm building version 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT, directories for both versions would share the same packages.

Now, if you were wanting to show which artifacts being used in a project, you could just use the dependency plugin.  Two of my favorite commands at the beginning of a maven project are:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i need to scan a remote repository and save the result to a database so i can search then later

Comment: With the end result being a classes hierarchy of the remote repository?

Comment: The end result should be a list of  all artefacts.